# Can we achieve MVVM architecture for Android by using only viewbinding?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewbinding

I want to develop application by using MVVM architecture, so i want to know whether i can use only viewbinding concept as databinding takes longer compilation time.

Can we achieve MVVM architecture without using databinding and by using only viewbinding concept?

Comment: How big is your project that you need to take the Compile time difference of those into consideration? Yes, you can. Data Binding is not a condition for MVVM.

Comment: "Can we achieve MVVM architecture without using databinding and by using only viewbinding" - of course, you just need to do the manual wiring boilerplate (observer pattern one/two way binding) that databinding abstracts through code generation and binding adapters. Ultimately what you gain in compile time, you lose many times over in manual coding and potential errors, which are caught at compile time.